# Will iOS 8's action extensibility be enabled in the default mail application?

Tags: ios, ios8, extensibility, ios-app-extension

With the advent of extensibility in iOS 8, will one be able to make an action extension for the default iOS 8 mail application?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from your question what you wish to extend in Mail, but there are [seven types of extensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/index.html):

- **Today (iOS and OS X)** - Get a quick update or perform a quick task in the Today view of Notification Center
  (A Today extension is called a widget)
- **Share (iOS and OS X)** - Post to a sharing website or share content with others
- **Action (iOS and OS X)** - Manipulate or view content within the context of another app
- **Photo Editing (iOS)** - Edit a photo or video within the Photos app
- **Finder (OS X)** - Use a remote file storage service in OS X
- **Storage Provider (iOS)** - Choose a document from among the set of documents the current iOS app can access
- **Custom keyboard (iOS)** - Replace the iOS system keyboard with a custom keyboard for use in all apps

So if your idea fits into one of those categories then the answer is yes.

Comment: Thanks very much! Say you had an App that looks up customer information using the customer's email address.  Could you create an action extension within mail that takes the recipient's email address in the "to field"? Makes the query in the app using the recipient's email address and then pastes that information into the body of the email?